# How to scrape the nested data from Linkedin page using Selenium and Python

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, linkedin-api

I am sitting with a project for my masters, where I would like to scrape LinkedIn. As far as I am now, I ran into a problem when I want to scrape the education pages of users (eg. https://www.linkedin.com/in/williamhgates/details/education/)

I would like to scrape all the educations of the users. In this example I would like to scrape "Harvard University" under `mr1 hoverable-link-text t-bold`, but I can't see to get to it.

Here's the HTML at code from Linkedin:

```
<li class="pvs-list__paged-list-item artdeco-list__item pvs-list__item--line-separated " id="profilePagedListComponent-ACoAAA8BYqEBCGLg-vT-ca6mMEqkpp9nVffJ3hc-EDUCATION-VIEW-DETAILS-profile-ACoAAA8BYqEBCGLg-vT-ca6mMEqkpp9nVffJ3hc-NONE-da-DK-0">
                        <!----><div class="pvs-entity
    pvs-entity--padded pvs-list__item--no-padding-when-nested
    
    ">
  <div>
        <a class="optional-action-target-wrapper 
        display-flex" target="_self" href="https://www.linkedin.com/company/1646/">
        <div class="ivm-image-view-model  pvs-entity__image ">
    <div class="ivm-view-attr__img-wrapper ivm-view-attr__img-wrapper--use-img-tag display-flex
    
    ">
<!---->      <img width="48" src="https://media-exp1.licdn.com/dms/image/C4E0BAQF5t62bcL0e9g/company-logo_100_100/0/1519855919126?e=1668643200&amp;v=beta&amp;t=BL0HxGNOasVbI3u39HBSL3n7H-yYADkJsqS3vafg-Ak" loading="lazy" height="48" alt="Harvard University logo" id="ember59" class="ivm-view-attr__img--centered EntityPhoto-square-3  lazy-image ember-view">
</div>
  </div>
    </a>

  </div>

  <div class="display-flex flex-column full-width align-self-center">
    <div class="display-flex flex-row justify-space-between">
          <a class="optional-action-target-wrapper 
          display-flex flex-column full-width" target="_self" href="https://www.linkedin.com/company/1646/">
        <div class="display-flex align-items-center">
            <span class="mr1 hoverable-link-text t-bold">
              <span aria-hidden="true"><!---->Harvard University<!----></span><span class="visually-hidden"><!---->Harvard University<!----></span>
            </span>
<!----><!----><!---->        </div>
<!---->          <span class="t-14 t-normal t-black--light">
            <span aria-hidden="true"><!---->1973 - 1975<!----></span><span class="visually-hidden"><!---->1973 - 1975<!----></span>
          </span>
<!---->      </a>


<!---->
      <div class="pvs-entity__action-container">
<!---->      </div>
    </div>

      <div class="pvs-list__outer-container">
<!---->    <ul class="pvs-list
        
        ">
        <li class=" ">
                <div class="pvs-list__outer-container">
<!----><!----><!----></div>

        </li>
    </ul>
<!----></div>
  </div>
</div>

                </li>
```

I have tried the following code:

```
education = driver.find_element("xpath", '//*[@id="profilePagedListComponent-ACoAAA8BYqEBCGLg-vT-ca6mMEqkpp9nVffJ3hc-EDUCATION-VIEW-DETAILS-profile-ACoAAA8BYqEBCGLg-vT-ca6mMEqkpp9nVffJ3hc-NONE-da-DK-0"]/div/div[2]/div[1]/a/div/span/span[1]/').text
print(education)
```

I keep getting the error:

```
Message: no such element: Unable to locate element:
```

Can anybody help? I would love to have a script that loops through the educations, and save place of education and the year of educations.

Comment: May I suggest you use Playwright for your project? It's supports Python and is a pleasure to work with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To extract the text ***Harvard University*** ideally you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*visibility_of_element_located()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50474905/7429447) and you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

  ```
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "ul.pvs-list>li span.hoverable-link-text span"))).text)
  ```
- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//ul[@class='pvs-list ']/li//span[contains(@class, 'hoverable-link-text')]//span"))).text)
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

> You can find a relevant discussion in [How to retrieve the text of a WebElement using Selenium - Python](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55241232/7429447)

Answer (score 1):

Thank you everyone!

I ended up with this code under that worked.

```
get_education_school = [my_elem.text for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//ul[@class='pvs-list ']/li//span[contains(@class, 'hoverable-link-text')]//span[1]")))]

get_education_years = [my_elem.text for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//ul[@class='pvs-list ']/li//span[contains(@class, 't-14 t-normal t-black--light')]//span[1]")))]

results_education_school = []
results_education_years = []
for i,j in zip(get_education_school, get_education_years):
    results_education_school.append(i)
    results_education_years.append(j)

print(results_education_school)
print(results_education_years)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would first get the list for the education section.

```py
education_list = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'ul.pvs-list')
# loop through education_list for place and years
# would recommend relative locators for this task.
# find the image and get the first and second span with text inside of them.
```

I am adding further details to the code now. Please hold.

Comment: Hi Wonhyeong,

If I use the statement written, I get the following error (I had already tried that also, to get the list).

NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"ul.pvs-list"}

Answer (score 0):

You can use below properties to identify the school name list:

```
ancestorClass="optional-action-target-wrapper display-flex flex-column full-width" class="display-flex align-items-center" tag="DIV"
```

Use these properties to identify the year list:

```
ancestorClass="optional-action-target-wrapper display-flex flex-column full-width" class="t-14 t-normal t-black--light" tag="SPAN"
```

You may use above info to compose an XPath to locate the list, or if you don't mind using other python libraries, there is a sample code in [GitHub](https://github.com/automation9417/automation-samples/tree/main/LinkedInEducation) to scrape the school and year.

Answer (score 0):

@Nadia S. you can try the following code. I have provided comments inline inside the code.

```
    @Test
    public void linkedInTest() {
        driver.get("https://www.linkedin.com");

        // You need to enter the credentials for your linkedin below for login
        driver.findElement(By.id("session_key")).sendKeys("");
        driver.findElement(By.id("session_password")).sendKeys("");
        driver.findElement(By.className("sign-in-form__submit-button")).click();
        driver.get("https://www.linkedin.com/in/williamhgates/details/education/");

        //Wait for the Education details to get populated. 
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(7));
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(
                By.xpath("//div[@class = 'pvs-list__container']//div[@class = 'scaffold-finite-scroll__content']/ul")));
        
        //Take all elements showing education details in a list 
        List<WebElement> allEducation = driver.findElements(By
                .xpath("//div[@class = 'pvs-list__container']//div[@class = 'scaffold-finite-scroll__content']/ul/li"));
        //Extract details of each education item in the list. 
        //Below the details are directed to console. You can use a collection to store them.
        for (WebElement oneEducation : allEducation) {
            WebElement education = oneEducation.findElement(
                    By.xpath(".//*[contains(@class,\"mr1 hoverable-link-text\")]/span[@aria-hidden='true']"));
            System.out.print("Education - " + education.getText());
            try {
                WebElement educationType = oneEducation
                        .findElement(By.cssSelector(".t-14.t-normal span[aria-hidden='true']"));
                System.out.print("      Education Type - " + educationType.getText());
            } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
                System.out.print("      Education Type - " + "is Not Specified");
            }
            try {
                WebElement educationYear = oneEducation
                        .findElement(By.cssSelector(".t-14.t-normal.t-black--light span[aria-hidden='true']"));
                System.out.println("        Education Year - " + educationYear.getText());
            } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
                System.out.println("        Education Year - " + "is Not Specified");
            }
        }

    }
```